# Is is possible to create a data collection set, in Windows 7's Performance Monitor, that collects bandwidth used per process?

Tags: windows, performance, bandwidth, display

Resource monitor shows bandwidth used per process.  However, I've not found a way to accomplish this with the Performance Monitor in Windows 7.

Is this possible to gather bandwidth used per process from within the native Microsoft tool, Performance Monitor?

If so, then how?  Two days of internet searches have only yielded circular results, with no actual answers.

A third-party tool will not suffice for a multitude of reasons, unless this is impossible using features integrated in Windows 7 alone.

Comment: @user67052 - This question is about a "workstation" Operating System.  It will probably be migrated to SuperUser.  ServerFault is more geared toward "server" OS's and enterprise-level issues.

Answer (score 1):

See this article, specifically "Network Tracing with Netsh.exe"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff625276.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain you can't do this from the Performance Monitor.

You may have some luck with the [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f), which I believe comes included with a 'GetProcessId' parser plugin, and can be used to perform all kinds of analysis.

It'll be a bit of work to set up, but it should do the job.

Good Luck!